# if it's an android place a button or if it's iOS place another button

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, cross-platform

Someone knows how to use xamarin forms in the XAML code, ¿if it's an android place a button or if it's iOS place another button?

this is my code

```
<ContentPage.Content>


    <ListView x:Name="ListElement" SeparatorColor="Red"
              Header=""
              HasUnevenRows="True">


        <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              **<!-- if is android** 
                <Grid Padding="20" 
                        BackgroundColor="#DE6B51">
                    <Label Text="Bandeja de Entrada" TextColor="White"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large" />
                </Grid>
              **-->**
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.HeaderTemplate>


    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe be not as clean as possible, in XAML i would create 2 buttons and add them a property, first one:

```
IsVisible="{Binding IsAndroid}"
```

and second one:

```
IsVisible="{Binding IsAndroid, Converter={StaticResource not}}"
```

OR

```
IsVisible="{Binding IsIOS}"
```

if you dont want to use a converter just create both props in your model

```
    private bool _IsAndroid;
    public bool IsAndroid
    {
        get { return Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android; }
    }

    private bool _IsIOS;
    public bool IsIOS
    {
        get { return Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> if it's an android place a button or if it's iOS place another button?

Yes, it's possible. In XAML, you can code for example like this:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
    <OnPlatform.Android>
        <!--view for Android-->
    </OnPlatform.Android>
    <OnPlatform.iOS>
        <!--view for iOS-->
    </OnPlatform.iOS>
</OnPlatform>
```

Or I suggest you to read this document: [Mobile - Embedding Native Views in Your Xamarin.Forms Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt790186.aspx), it tells several ways to embed different view for different platforms.

Comment: I tried that solution, but if you notice I use "<ContentPage.Content>" so if you add those lines it does not work.

Comment: @Ceregol, you want to add different view as content of `ContentPage`? It should work, could you please show me your code?